# Можно ли не помещать элемент в массив в генераторе массивов?

Tags: python, массивы

При создании генератора массива в python можно использовать условный оператор:
`[i if i == x else None for i in arr]`, можно ли как то пропустить выполнение блока else и не помещать никакое значение в массив на выходе если условие не удовлетворено?

Comment: `[i for i in arr if i == x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно - делается вот так

```
res = [i for i in arr if i == x]
```

так же можно использовать способы потяжелее:

```
res = list(filter(lambda i: i == x, arr))
```

Comment: первый вариант быстрее чем второй.